$ \pi^0\to \gamma\gamma$ parity conservation
Let's consider the decay process $\pi^0\to \gamma \gamma$. After we spontaneously broke the chiral symmetry of QCD coupled to an abelian gauge field $A^\mu$, we end up with the Goldstone boson lagrangian. The simplest term that can give $\pi^0\to \gamma \gamma$ is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} \supset g\pi^0 \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}.
\end{equation}
The derivative terms and the quark mass terms are suppressed.
We know that $\pi^0$ has odd parity. How can we see from the lagrangian that this process conserve parity? How is parity trasforming the fields in the lagrangian?
I guess having the Levi-Civita tensor plays a role in seeing that it's parity invariant, but I don't know how to formalise this.

Yes, the Levi-Civita symbol has negative parity. Reverse all three spacelike directions.

As @Cosmas Zachos said in his comment, the Levi-Civita pseudotensor $\epsilon$ has negative parity. But why?
This is the case because $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} := \sqrt{-g}\ \varepsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$, where $\varepsilon$ is the L-C symbol, which is coordinate independent. Now, under a parity reversal, $\sqrt{-g}\to -\sqrt{-g}$.
In Minkowski spacetime, we have $\sqrt{-g}=1$, which is the reason why we use interchangeably the L-C pseudotensor and symbol, which has created many headaches and confusions to students (like myself).

Note: We call the LC a pseudotensor, and not a tensor, because it transforms oddly under parity.

Another useful term to search would be Tensor Density
